# PHP Array Looping

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 10
            [date_modified] => 2010-07-25 01:51:48
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 16
            [date_modified] => 2010-07-26 14:37:24
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 27
            [date_modified] => 2010-07-26 16:49:17
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 79
            [date_modified] => 2010-08-08 18:53:20
        )

)
```

and what I need to do is print out the user id's comma seperated so:

10, 16, 27, 79

I'm guessing it'd be in a for loop but i'm looking for the most efficient way to do it in PHP

Oh and the Array name is: $mArray

I'm trying the methods below but I keep getting this error: **Fatal error**: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: replace the array indexing with arraow notation. no one realized they were objects. `->user_id` instead of `['user_id']` i changed my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstTime = true;
foreach($mArray as $k => $cur)
{
    //echo $firstTime ? $firstTime = false : ', '; //this one-liner cna replace the following two, kind of unclear but i like it
    if (!$firstTime) echo ', ';
    else $firstTime = false;
    echo $cur->user_id;
}
```

This is more fun:

```
$f = function($a,$b) {$c = $a ? ', ' : ''; return $a . $c . $b->user_id;};
echo array_reduce($f, $mArray, '');
```

James alludes to using `join`, which is a good idea and avoids the trailing comma issue

```
$newArr = array_map(function($x) {return $x->user_id;}, $mArray); //make array of just user-ids
echo join(', ',$newArr);  // implode === join, join is an alias of implode
```

Comment: If you use James' method mentioned above, you can just trim at the end.  But, for your loop you can have a "isFirstItem" bool that is changed to false after the first loop.  Then an if statement checking for false on isFirstItem pre-pends a comma instead of putting one after from there on out.

Comment: yes, that will work.  also, if you assume that he has numeric indices like he does in the example you can just do `if ($k == 0)`.  i was trying to leave something to the author of the question.  if it were me, id use the reduce function

Comment: Got thiss error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: o wow.  i dont believe i, or anyone else, noticed this.  we all assumed it was an array of arrays, not objects.  ive made an edit

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
$output = "";
foreach($mArray as $i => $val) {
    $output .= $val->user_id . ", " ;
}
$output = trim($output, ", ");
```

Heck, you could probably use `join` and remove the foreach loop altogether!

Comment: Keep getting this error: <b>Fatal error</b>: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: @softm - tell me you didnt downvote over that.  everyone overlooked it, are you going to downvote all of us?

Comment: @James yes, its pretty petty that anyone complained or downvoted at all, so i voted yours up in response.  btw, you're still mssing an underscore.  i may have been downvoted for the same, not sure

Comment: @Jon, woops again! Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

```
$length = sizeof($mArray);
sort($mArray);
foreach($mArray as $item)
{
    echo $item['user_id'] . ($item !== $mArray[$length]) ? ', ' : '';
}
```

Remove the sort if you don't need it in order.

Comment: IN PHP Concatenation is period not a plus :)

Comment: @softm Thanks, I didn't even realize it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to make a delimited list (in this case by a comma), I start with an array and implode() it with the delimiter.  In this case the delimiter would be the comma + the space:

```
$user_ids = array();
foreach($mArray as $item) {
    $user_ids[] = $item['user_id'];
}
$comma_delimited_list = implode(', ', $user_ids);//magic
```